# Generate a permanent UUID for host using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I am looking to generate a unique uuid for every host computer using the pyhton UUID. My aim is to get  the mechine node id and use it for creating a uuid.

```
import uuid
node_id=uuid.getnode()
print(node_id)
```

The result is

```
219414503929041
```

How can i use this node_id  with uuid.UUID() to create a valid uuid, which is permanent on a machine

```
print(uuid.UUID(int=uuid.getnode()))
00000000-0000-0000-0000-c78e6b90b4d1
```

This looks like not a good uuid , can some one point me to the correct direction

Comment: If you use `uuid.uuid1()` it used the node id and clock sequence any way.

Comment: @sherin what is wrong with your UUID? it is good.

Comment: the uuid.uuid1() is returning differnt uuids every time. It is not a permanent id